# Is the set of all pairs of real numbers uncountable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

My hypothesis is that $\mathbb{R \times R}$,  the set of all pairs $(r_1, r_2)$, of real numbers is uncountable. I understand that the set of all pairs of natural numbers is countable. But could someone explain why the set of all pairs of real numbers uncountable? I am having trouble proving it using diagolization

Comment: Yes, because $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable.

Comment: Note $\Bbb R \cong\{(r, 0) : r \in \Bbb R\} = \Bbb R \times \{0\} \subset \Bbb {R \times R}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that $\Bbb R \times \{0\} \subset \Bbb R \times \Bbb R$ has the same quantity of elements that $\Bbb R$¹. So if you prove that $\Bbb R$ is uncountable, you're done.

¹ Actually $|\Bbb R| = |\Bbb R^n|$ for every $n$.

Comment: Thank you that was a great description. On a related note, could you explain why the set of all pairs of natural numbers countable? Are natural numbers countable thus the cartesian product is also countable?

Comment: Recall that a set $A$ is countable if there exists an injection $f: A \to \Bbb N$. The set $\Bbb N$ is countable because we have the bijection (in particular, an injection) $f: \Bbb N \to \Bbb N$ given by $f(n)=n$. The countable product of countable sets is countable. So $\Bbb N \times \Bbb N$ is also countable.

Answer (score 0):

Real numbers are uncountable, hence the Cartesian product of real numbers is uncountable.