# Is the Cartesian product of two uncountable sets uncountable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is Cartesian product of two uncountable sets uncountable?
Suppose we have a set of real numbers $R$, Can't it be shown that $R$ is uncountable by Cantor's diagonalization method, so it follows that the Cartesian product of two sets of real numbers in uncountable?

Comment: Similar question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1294585/is-the-set-of-all-pairs-of-real-numbers-uncountable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an easy proof (if you already know every subset of $\Bbb N$ is countable) -- **please only look at this after you've already attempted the problem yourself given the other hints**:

Suppose $R$ and  $Y$ are uncountable sets.  Suppose by contradiction $R \times Y$ is countable.  Let $\phi :  R \times Y \to \Bbb N$ be the bijection you can find.  Then fix some $y \in Y$ and look at $ A = \{ (r, y) \mid r \in R \}$.  Note that $A \subseteq R \times Y$.

Then the restriction map $\phi \mid_{A} : A \to \phi(A)$ is a bijection between $A$ and $\phi(A)$ (why?).  But $\phi(A)$ is a subset of $\Bbb N$, and so it is countable.  Thus, $A$ is countable.

But there is a clear bijection between $R$ and $A$ by sending $r \mapsto (r,y)$.  You should check that this is a bijection.  Then composing this map and $\phi$ gives you a bijection between $R$ and a $\phi(A)$, and $\phi(A)$ is a subset of $\Bbb N$ and thus countable.  So $R$ is countable.  Contradiction!  Since we assumed $R$ was not countable.  So $R \times Y$ is uncountable, as desired.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** This is done in two steps:

1. If $A$ and $B$ are not empty, then there is an injective function from $A$ into $A\times B$.
2. If $A$ is uncountable there is an injective function from $A$ into $D$, then $D$ is uncountable.

Comment: Couldn't come up with a proof to your 1st hint, but in the process I came up with something different along those lines. If $A$ is uncountable and $B\neq \varnothing \Rightarrow \exists b \in B$, fix this $b$ and define $S_b = \{(a,b) : a \in A\}$ then the mapping $f : A \to S_b$ given by $f(a)= (a,b)$ is an injection from $A$ into $S_b \subseteq A \times B$, $S_b$ is uncountable and by simple proof by contradiction, I can show that every superset of an uncountable set is uncountable. Hence $A \times B$ is uncountable. Is this correct? All this and I still don't know how to prove 1 though :'-)

Comment: That *is* the proof of the first hint. A function from $A$ into $A\times B$ does not mean that it needs to be surjective somehow. It means that $f$ is a function whose domain is $A$ and whose range is a subset of $A\times B$.

Comment: Note that, I didn't mention what $B\neq \varnothing$ is, it could be countable or uncountable.

Comment: Note that I didn't mention it either.

Comment: Ah I don't know why I thought function wouldn't be "injective function" if I define it like that. Maybe it's because I forgot about fixing $b$. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Do it by contradiction. Assume there is a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and the cartesian product and show this would imply there is a bijection with at least one of the original sets.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Cantor diagonalization argument to show that $$A \text{ and } B \text{ countable } \implies A\times B \text{ countable.}$$ So: $$A \times B \text{ uncountable} \implies A \text{ or } B \text{ is uncountable}.$$

Alternatively, you can fix $b \in B$. Then $A \times \{b\}$ has the same quantity of elements that $A$, which is uncountable, and $A \times \{b\} \subset A \times B$. So $A \times B$ contains an uncountable set.

Comment: but if you wanted to show this for infinitely many countable sets, if any one of those countable sets contained $\geq 2$ elements, then the infinite product would be uncountable, right?

Answer (score 0):

Let $b$ be an arbitrary element in $B$. If $A$ and $B$ are uncountable and $A\times B$ is countable, then $A\times\{b\}$ is also countable, because $A\times\{b\}\subset A\times B$. But $A$ is uncountable iff $A\times\{b\}$ does. This contradicts.